# SPIFFS on an embedded ARM project with 32mb IS25LQ032B device

Tags: arm, filesystems, spi, flash-memory, spiffs

I've been looking at the SPIFFS file system project on https://github.com/pellepl/spiffs and it seems like it has a pretty large user community.  I've been looking at the WIKI on the integration and configuration which seems to be well documented.  I didn't see a user group forum? is there one?

My question pertains to the actual formatting of the flash device, within the examples shown in the WIKI pages I didn't example code on how to format the flash.  There's a description, but it doesn't show an example of how to use the API.

I'm hoping someone might know of example of how to use the APIs.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm all set, I took another look at the API's and I figured out how to use them to mount and format the spi flash to initialize it.  I ran thru the test example and it works.  It went better than expected.